# jQuery ui tabs form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jsp

I'm using tabs to navigate my web application. On each tab is separate file which contains form to receive input from user and display table of data according to input.

I want to ask how can I display a result table in the same tabs and make my input form ready to receive difference input again.

Here is my code

```
<div id="tabs">
      <ul>
            <li><a href="t1.htm">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="t2.htm">Tab 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="t3.htm">Tab 3</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

example of my t1.htm

```
<form action="table.htm" method="POST">
       First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">
       <br />
       Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" />
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

while `table.htm` will create dynamic table according to the input of `firstname` and `lastname`. But, right now when I submit the form it will open `table.htm` right away but I want it to only display the result below the input form.

Comment: Is your code purely client side or you are using java or servlets in the server end?

Comment: @GopakumarNG While you're editing, you can also remove salutations and thanks (it's implied when you upvote/accept answers anyway), and please use backticks only for code (or filenames) but not for keywords or technology names

Comment: my friend will provide service that query the data from database for me but i have to make the content in jquery tab able to call the service and use returned result to build dynamic table in the same tab

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly (read twice)

You can simply use jquery to send the ajax request and your form is ready for next input.

The form contains the fields

```
<form id="myform">
...
<button id="sub">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The below div will contain the ajax-request response, which is mostly a table in your case.

```
<div id="resultContainer"></div>
```

Here's the script to submit the form through ajax to some url

```
<script>
$("#sub").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myjsp.jsp",
            data: $("#myform").serialize(),
            complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
                $("#resultContainer").html(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something along these lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('form:eq(0)').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "table.htm",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'text/html',
            success: function(response) {
                $(this).after(response);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

and you need to give the form an `id` attribute.